# Loading a CSV file into BigQuery with one column containing all empty values

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am looking to append the following [file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bnjUZzxyS-nhjP45czlD-EDFs3ITowqj/view?usp=sharing) using the Python API into a BigQuery table that has the below defined schema:

```
[
   {
    "name": "batsman",
    "type": "STRING",
    "mode": "NULLABLE"
   },
   {
    "name": "batting_team",
    "type": "STRING",
    "mode": "NULLABLE"
   },
   {
    "name": "bowler",
    "type": "STRING",
    "mode": "NULLABLE"
   },
   {
    "name": "city",
    "type": "STRING",
    "mode": "NULLABLE"
   },
   {
    "name": "date",
    "type": "DATE",
    "mode": "NULLABLE"
   },
   {
    "name": "delivery",
    "type": "FLOAT",
    "mode": "NULLABLE"
   },
   {
    "name": "extras",
    "type": "INTEGER",
    "mode": "NULLABLE"
   },
   {
    "name": "extras_type",
    "type": "STRING",
    "mode": "NULLABLE"
   },
   {
    "name": "inning",
    "type": "INTEGER",
    "mode": "NULLABLE"
   },
   {
    "name": "match_code",
    "type": "INTEGER",
    "mode": "NULLABLE"
   },
   {
    "name": "non_striker",
    "type": "STRING",
    "mode": "NULLABLE"
   },
   {
    "name": "player_out",
    "type": "STRING",
    "mode": "NULLABLE"
   },
   {
    "name": "runs",
    "type": "INTEGER",
    "mode": "NULLABLE"
   },
   {
    "name": "team1",
    "type": "STRING",
    "mode": "NULLABLE"
   },
   {
    "name": "team2",
    "type": "STRING",
    "mode": "NULLABLE"
   },
   {
    "name": "toss_decision",
    "type": "STRING",
    "mode": "NULLABLE"
   },
   {
    "name": "toss_winner",
    "type": "STRING",
    "mode": "NULLABLE"
   },
   {
    "name": "total",
    "type": "INTEGER",
    "mode": "NULLABLE"
   },
   {
    "name": "venue",
    "type": "STRING",
    "mode": "NULLABLE"
   },
   {
    "name": "wicket_fielders",
    "type": "STRING",
    "mode": "NULLABLE"
   },
   {
    "name": "wicket_kind",
    "type": "STRING",
    "mode": "NULLABLE"
   },
   {
    "name": "win_margin",
    "type": "INTEGER",
    "mode": "NULLABLE"
   },
   {
    "name": "win_type",
    "type": "STRING",
    "mode": "NULLABLE"
   },
   {
    "name": "winner",
    "type": "STRING",
    "mode": "NULLABLE"
   }
  ]
```

The code that I am using to append into BigQuery is as follows:

```
def insert_data_in_bq(bucketname, csv_filepath, table_id='ipl'):
    """Appends a csv to a BigQuery table."""
    client = bigquery.Client()
    dataset_id = 'cric'
    dataset_ref = client.dataset(dataset_id)
    job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig()
    job_config.autodetect = True
    job_config.skip_leading_rows = 1
    job_config.source_format = bigquery.SourceFormat.CSV
    # job_config.null_marker = 'NULL'
    uri = 'gs://' + bucketname + '/' + csv_filepath
    load_job = client.load_table_from_uri(uri, dataset_ref.table(table_id), 
    job_config=job_config)  # API request
    print('Starting job {}'.format(load_job.job_id))
    load_job.result()  # Waits for table load to complete.
    print('Job finished.')
    print('Loaded {} rows.'.format(load_job.output_rows))
```

However whenever I load the file I get an error saying:

`BadRequest: 400 Invalid schema update. Field win_margin has changed type from INTEGER to STRING`

A normal file would look like [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WbZbHIUU6x8PXX1j5fPzaiX2yXizbSQc/view?usp=sharing).

What should I do so that I can keep the `win_margin` column as `INTEGER` and yet still be able to load this file that contains all empty rows for a column?

Comment: When you say: " keep the win_type column as INTEGER", but on your example file win_type is a string. Did you meant win_margin?

Comment: I mean `win_margin`. Have edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

As you see BigQuery will not allow you to add empty value to an Integer field so you need to fill this field either when creating the file or during the upload, for example:

1. When building the file make sure `win_margin` is not empty put 0 or
   null
2. If not possible you will need to update your python code to
   update the field value before the upload
3. Create a formula in the Sheet itself to fill up the field
4. Upload the file to another table in BQ and run SQL command to move data from 1 table to another

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the table schema, where the type of the `win_margin` column is specified explicitly. You can do it by setting `job_config.schema` field and setting `job_config.autodetect` to `False`.

Below is the function you can use to read the schema from a file:

```
def read_bigquery_schema_from_file(filepath):
    file_content = open(filepath).read()
    json_content = json.loads(file_content)
    return read_bigquery_schema_from_json_recursive(json_content)

def read_bigquery_schema_from_json_recursive(json_schema):
    """
    CAUTION: Recursive function
    This method can generate BQ schemas for nested records
    """
    result = []
    for field in json_schema:
        if field.get('type').lower() == 'record' and field.get('fields'):
            schema = SchemaField(
                name=field.get('name'),
                field_type=field.get('type', 'STRING'),
                mode=field.get('mode', 'NULLABLE'),
                description=field.get('description'),
                fields=read_bigquery_schema_from_json_recursive(field.get('fields'))
            )
        else:
            schema = SchemaField(
                name=field.get('name'),
                field_type=field.get('type', 'STRING'),
                mode=field.get('mode', 'NULLABLE'),
                description=field.get('description')
            )
        result.append(schema)
    return result
```